# Why are children more active than adults?

Tags: metabolism, children

I have observed that children are usually more active than adults. For example, in the morning they get up and start playing, they have their lunch and get up and start running, while as adults they are relatively lazy.

Why is this so or is it that my observations are somehow errenous?
Thank you.

Comment: Personally as an adult I don't find running around exciting. But adult people definitely would wake up early if that means they are having a resort trip that day or something. Also could be suitable for psy.SE.

Comment: Have you done any research into whether or not this is backed up by any scientific research, or if it's just your own observations?

Comment: @4galaxy7 my own observations. I made it clear in my question.

Comment: I know - but in Biology (and science in general), it's useful and expected to do some research into whether or not your observations are backed up by some kind of scientific research, or whether they are just anecdotal observations.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It was just by observing and I've studied biology only when I was a kid.

Comment: @rus9384 nice viewpoint. Definitely plausible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a great question!

As I see you are new and you have explained within the comments above that you haven't studied biology much I will keep the explanation short and sweet.

Young children have fatigue resistant muscles and they also recover faster from high intensity workouts when compared to adults. Children have also been found to use more aerobic respiration when compared to adults during high intensity workouts. This means the child will feel less fatigue and so can continue exercising for longer. As the muscles also recover faster, the child is able to get up and start exercising again much faster than the adult as they will still be recovering.

Aerobic fitness at the muscle level decreases however once the child reaches adulthood and this explains why children have more energy and can play/exercise for much longer. They experience less fatigue and recover faster.

I hope this answers your question.

References:

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphys.2018.00387/full

Comment: Fantastic answer, do you have any references for further reading? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please link the references. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I have added a link to a study which looks at the metabolic and fatigue profiles of prepubertal children and well-trained adult endurance athletes. The study had some interesting findings. They found that the children recovered very quickly even faster than the well-trained adult endurance athletes. I hope this helps and is what you are looking for!

Comment: The reference also appeared to suggest they may have bigger lung-to-muscle-mass-ratio and good muscle aeration and circulation and heart characteristics as well as different muscle types.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I was hesitant in adding these points to my answer as Yasir Sadiq hasn't studied biology much and I didn't want to confuse him. This is also why I didn't go into depth in my answer about fatigue. I remember when I was new to biology and a lot of the answers that were too in depth took me a while to decipher and made learning difficult for me.

Comment: Thank you, :-)  .